Metaplex Umi Devnet blockhash errors
I have a token creator using Metaplex Umi on Devnet.  It has been running fine for weeks but today it's stopped working.
I keep getting this in browser console error:
Failed to create token: Simulation failed. Message: Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found. Logs: []. Catch the SendTransactionError and call getLogs() on it for full details.
I have attempted many workarounds all day including different RPC endpoints, Quicknode and Helius.  Retries and generating fresh blocks don't seem to fix the issue, the error just does not go away.
Is there a problem with Umi on Devnet?
